# Logout after clicking URL link results in "headers already sent" error

Tags: plugin-development, customization, logout

> **Warning**: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at D:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\formatting.php:5688) in D:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\pluggable.php on line 961

I am using this function

```
if(isset($_GET['logout']))
{
    //echo "test";
    //die();
    wp_logout();
    wp_redirect("http://localhost:2124/wordpress/game/");
    exit;
    //wp_logout_url("http://localhost:2124/wordpress/logout_custom");
    //exit();
    //die();
    //wp_redirect(site_url().'/login');
    //return "<script> location.replace('".site_url()."/login');</script>"; 
    //exit();
    //wp_redirect(site_url()."/login/");
}
```

Comment: You should do redirects within a hook before content is rendered. Try running that code inside a template_redirect hooked function.

Answer (score 1):

You should do redirects within a hook before content is rendered. Try running that code inside a template_redirect hooked function.

Something like this:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'my_redirects', 5 );
function my_redirects(){
    // Your code here
}
```